# Conditional execution of code segments

Tags: r

I am working on a data set using both my laptop and a cloud facility. I want to compute some "computation-heavy" code chunks only when working on the cloud.

So far, I have chosen a not very elegant way to do so. I have added `##OPT##` prefixes to segments which I want to execute only when in the cloud. I then simply remove these prefixes and run the script when in the cloud.

Now my question: is there a way that I can select in the beginning of the script once whether to execute these segments or not and then skip these segments if the argument is set to "false"? I have tried with if conditions but this is very cumbersome.

Comment: you can use simple `if` statements with a parameter you set to TRUE / FALSE at the beginning of your script i.e. `in_cloud <- TRUE` and then `if(in_cloud) {...}`

Comment: or you can create two seperate scripts: local.R & cloud.R, and source the appropriate one.

Comment: Assuming your laptop is Windows, we can do something like: `if(Sys.info()["sysname"] != "Windows"){ ... some heave code ... }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To further explain the comment of docendo discimus, just define a parameter at the beginning of your script:

```
execpart <- TRUE #and change to FALSE if you don't want to execute
```

Then wrap the whole part of your script which should only be executed situationally in:

```
if(execpart){
## your script
}
```

You could even define multiple parameters for different parts of your script at the beginning. That would give you the option to set up the execution of your script with a few quick changes.

Note that `if` looks for `TRUE/FALSE`, so you do not need to specify `(execpart == TRUE)` in your `if`-condition.

Comment: The question states that they have tried `if` statements and find them very cumbersome. I assume that they were looking for an alternative solution. I agree, however, that this is probably the simplest way of doing it.

Comment: Yeah, I assumed they somehow used `if` in a overly complicated way, as this solution costs neither much time nor a lot of code.

Comment: I am still a beginner at R and I was adding the `if` condition to each line of code. This version with `if() {}` is perfect and exactly what I wanted!

Comment: Glad I (and @docendodiscimus) could help.

Answer (score 5):

If you use an R notebook in RStudio, you can include the different code in different code chunks in the document. Code chunks are defined like:

````
```{r}
"hello world!"
```
````

Doing this allows you to quite easily run only the chunks that you want to run. Additionally, if you wish to run all of the chunks, you can do so.

Any given chunk possess an option called `eval` which dictates whether or not they should be run. This can take a value from an expression so you can essentially do something like:

````
```{r label}
is_cloud <- FALSE #or TRUE
```

```{r conditional, eval = is_cloud}
"hello world!"
```
````

and the chunk will be executed only if `is_cloud` is `TRUE`.

Answer (score 1):

In RStudio R notebooks is is convenient to combine the nice [suggestion in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45837363/3780389) with using "params" in the *notebook header*.  E.g.:

````
---
title: params example
output: html_notebook
params:
  in_cloud: yes
---

This one always runs:
```{r}
print("hello always")
```

This one only runs when in_cloud is TRUE:
```{r, eval=params$in_cloud}
print("hello, cloud")
```

Conditional blocks also work for other engines (like bash):  
```{bash, eval=params$in_cloud}
echo "hello, cloud, from bash"
```
````